# how to hide float message block at bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

hey guys i want to do one task to hide float message block at bottom, Basically i want that block initially at homepage but if i click on my post it will again show me this block at bottom. I want that block only at homepage and not to all my post so can anyone have idea how to do that?

see my code below and also i give my blog address below so that you can understand better from that address.

```html
<div class="demo-float">
<span class="df-hide"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
<div class="df-logo"></div>
<h3 style="font-weight: bold;padding: 15px;">aglaQuestion</h3>
<p class="excerpt">Get in Touch With Us Through</p>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/aglaquestion/" title="aglaQuestion - Tech News">Instagram Handle</a>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   var url="https://aglaquestion.blogspot.com/";
   if(!url){
   $('.demo-float').hide();}
   }
   else
   {
   $('.df-hide').on('click',function(){$('.demo-float').fadeOut(170);});
   }
   
   });
</script>
```

my blog address:- https://aglaquestion.blogspot.com/

Comment: why did you use the java tag?

Comment: You have error typo `$('.demo-float').hide();} <- delete that bracket`

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```
<div class="demo-float">
    <span class="df-hide"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
    <div class="df-logo"></div>
    <h3 style="font-weight: bold;padding: 15px;">aglaQuestion</h3>
    <p class="excerpt">Get in Touch With Us Through</p>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aglaquestion/" title="aglaQuestion - Tech News">Instagram Handle</a>

</div>


$(function () {
    var url = "https://aglaquestion.blogspot.com/";
    if (!url) {
        $('.demo-float').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.df-hide').on('click', function () { $('.demo-float').fadeOut(170); });
    }

});
```

You should be removed `}` after `$('.demo-float').hide();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="demo-float">
  <span class="df-hide"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
  <div class="df-logo"></div>
  <h3 style="font-weight: bold;padding: 15px;">aglaQuestion</h3>
  <p class="excerpt">Get in Touch With Us Through</p>
  <a href="https://www.instagram.com/aglaquestion/" title="aglaQuestion - Tech News">Instagram Handle</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
      var url = "https://aglaquestion.blogspot.com/";
      var currUrl = window.location.href;
      if (url !== currUrl) {
        $('.demo-float').fadeOut(170);
      }else{
        $('.demo-float').fadeIn(170);
      }
    }
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this logic works thanks guys for your support:)

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   var url = "https://aglaquestion.blogspot.com/";
   var CurrUrl = window.location.href;
    if (url != CurrUrl) {
        $('.demo-float').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.df-hide').on('click', function () { $('.demo-float').fadeOut(170); });
    }
   });
</script>
```